How can I hide hidden columns in the Grid from screen readers
I have column the has been hidden on the UI. 'hide': true for the first column. As a result, when I turn on Screen readers Narrator is announcing the second column as column2 eventhough the first column is hidden.
I tried to set the aria property of column1 (aria-hidden) to true but I did not find a proper way to do that.
const gridOptions: GridOptions<SalesRecord> = {
    // define column types
    columnTypes: {
        currency: {
            width: 150,
            valueFormatter: currencyFormatter,
        },
        shaded: {
            cellClass: "shaded-class",
        },
    },
    // define grid columns
    columnDefs: [
        { field: "productName", hide: true },
        // uses properties from currency type
        { field: "boughtPrice", type: "currency" },
        // uses properties from currency AND shaded types
        { field: "soldPrice", type: ["currency", "shaded"] },
    ],
    rowData: [
        { productName: "Lamp", boughtPrice: 100, soldPrice: 200 },
        { productName: "Chair", boughtPrice: 150, soldPrice: 300 },
        { productName: "Desk", boughtPrice: 200, soldPrice: 400 },
    ],
};

I want the screen reader to skip the columns that are hidden.

what screen reader are you talking about?

Narrator and NVDA

it's not like there is just ONE Narrator and when you say "Narrator" everybody knows what you are talking about. WHAT narrator? Windows Narrator, MacOS Narrator, android, some 3rd party, a js script on your page, etc.? And I don't know what NVDA is, but that may be just me not knowing what that is.
